# Where does nonclustered index physically exists

Tags: sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

I know that cluster index exist on the table itself, but where's the noncluster index and is pointer exist? I thought on "temp DB", but maybe i am wrong.

I did not find anything about it on the web.

Can you help me with it?

Comment: It exists on additional pages.  In some databases, this would be a separate store of "index" pages.  In some databases, it might be on data pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TempDb is a separate database, used by SQL (and maybe some of your stored procedures) to do intermediate work - hence the `Temp` in TempDb - so your indexes wouldn't be in there.  Non clustered index pages go into the same filegroup as the clustered index pages by default - but you can specify which filegroup they go into on the index declaration. See, for example: [Create Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql).

Also, if you want to ferret out where the data is, start with [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) and related system views.